# Flask dynamic input form, FormField returns blank POST data

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms

I'm working on a Flask webapp that asks (internal) users to select options for an arbitrary number of files that will be in a directory on our network so that some other scripts can process the files according to those options (not relevant to this issue, but if you're curious they are A/V files we need to process).

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to both dynamically generate the form fields needed (there could be 0 - dozens of files in the server directory the app is looking in) *and* collect the form data for each instance of the form class I created for the input objects. How do you shoehorn `n` form instances into an instance of another form class??

I have a base `IngestForm` class and an `ObjectForm` class that describes fields pertaining to each individual object. My basic suspicion is that `wtforms` can't have a subclass that includes other forms... but I can print everything out at various steps before the form gets `POST`ed and see all the data that I expect as a dict, and I can see that the sub-forms are there as `wtforms` objects. From my `index.html` template I can see all the expected data from the `ObjectForm` instances. But once the super-form is posted, all that is returned is a blank `choicesDict` (see below) and the `submit` value. Does the `IngestForm` instance get reinitialized or something weird when I hit `Submit`?

Here's what I have now. I have set up a dict for choices where each key is the path of the file in question and the value is an instance of the `ObjectForm` class:

**forms.py**

```
class ObjectForm(FlaskForm):
    """
    Fields for an individual object
    """
    targetFilePath = wtforms.HiddenField('targetObjectPath')
    option1 = wtforms.BooleanField('Option1?')
    option2 = wtforms.BooleanField("Option2?")
    # etc.

class IngestForm(FlaskForm):
    '''
    General input form
    '''
    choicesDict = {}
    # also tried just targetObject = wtforms.FormField(ObjectForm)
    submit = wtforms.SubmitField('Submit')
```

**routes.py**:

```
[import relevant stuff]
@app.route('/index',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    # GET A DICT OF PATHS AND BASENAMES TO PROCESS {'fullPath':'basename'}
    objects = listObjects.list_objects()

    class OneObject(forms.ObjectForm):
        pass

    choices = {}
    for path,_object in objects.items():
        choices[path] = OneObject(targetPath=path,targetBase=_object)

    # also tried setattr(forms.IngestForm,'choicesDict',choices)
    form = forms.IngestForm()
    form.choicesDict = choices

    if form.is_submitted():
        return redirect(url_for('status'))
    return render_template(
    'index.html',title='Index',objects=objects,form=form
    )

@app.route('/status',methods=['GET','POST'])
def status():
    # DO THE STUFF
```

**ingest.html** template:

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>Here are files to ingest:</h1>
    <form action="{{url_for('status')}}" method='POST'>
    <div>
        {% for item,vals in form.choicesDict.items() %}
        <p>{{vals.targetBase.data}}</p>
        <p>{{vals.option1.label}}{{vals.option1()}}</p>
        <p>{{vals.option2.label}} {{vals.option3()}}</p>
        <p>{{vals.etc.label}}{{vals.etc()}}</p>
        {%endfor%}  
    </div>

    {{form.submit()}}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**status.html** template just takes the POST data. Not really relevant here except to say I can see it is getting none of the `choicesDict`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I solved this in a really hack-y way but whatever. I used a jinja2 macro following [this](http://bear-z.com/python/render-bootstrap-3-forms-with-wtforms-and-jinja/) example and in my form template constructed field names/ids that are unique to the files I'm interested in.

So for each file `['a.mov','b.mov','c.mp4']` in my network directory, I create a dict like so: `{'a.mov': SubclassObjectForm, 'b.mov': SubclassObjectForm }` and I have a `MainForm` instance field that includes this dict. When I render the form, the jinja macro creates `name` and `id` attributes for the `<label>` and `<input>` fields as needed that include a prefix for the file in question.

For example `<input name='targetObjectFilePath-movieA.mov' value='/full/path/to/file' type='hidden>`.

When the form gets POSTed, it's just a matter of pulling the relevant bits of data in my view.

I hope this helps someone! It might not be elegant or 'pro' but it gets my task done. Next step... styling!

**forms.py**

```
class  ObjectForm(FlaskForm):
    """
    Fields for an individual object
    """
    targetFilePath = wtforms.HiddenField('targetObjectPath')
    targetBase = wtforms.HiddenField('targetObjectBasename')
    option1 = wtforms.BooleanField('Option1?')
    option2 = wtforms.BooleanField("Option2?")
    # etc.

class IngestForm(FlaskForm):
    '''
    General input form
    '''
    choicesDict = wtforms.HiddenField(default='no choices')
    submit = wtforms.SubmitField('Submit')
```

**routes.py**

```
[import relevant stuff]
@app.route('/index',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    # GET A DICT OF PATHS AND BASENAMES TO PROCESS {'fullPath':'basename'}
    objects = listObjects.list_objects()

    class OneObject(forms.ObjectForm):
        pass

    choices = {}
    for path,_object in objects.items():
        choices[path] = OneObject(targetPath=path,targetBase=_object)

    form = forms.IngestForm()
    form.choicesDict = choices

    return render_template(
    'index.html',title='Index',form=form
    )

@app.route('/status',methods=['GET','POST'])
def status():
    data = request.form.to_dict(flat=False)
    # DO THE STUFF
```

**index.html**

```
{% import "macros.html" as macros %}
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Here are files to ingest:</h1>
    <form action="{{ url_for('status') }}" method='POST'>
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ form.csrf_token }}

        {# iterate over the form dict with subforms included: #}
        {% for item,vals in form.choicesDict.items() %}
        <div>
            {# iterate over subform fields and include target file basename #}
            {% for field in vals %}
                {{macros.render_field(field,vals.targetBase.data)}}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {%endfor%}

    {{form.submit()}}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**macros.html**

```
{% macro render_field(field, uniqueName) %}
<p>
{# I only care about 2 kinds of data: filenames/paths and boolean options. #}
{% if field.type == 'BooleanField' %}
    <label for="{{ field.id }}-{{ uniqueName }}">{{ field.label.text }}</label>
    <input name="{{ field.id }}-{{ uniqueName }}" id="{{ field.id }}-{{ uniqueName }}" type="checkbox" default=""></input>
{# render hidden input for full path for later processing #}
{% elif field.name == 'targetPath' %}
    <input name="{{ field.id }}-{{ uniqueName }}" id="{{ field.id }}-{{ uniqueName }}" type="hidden" value="{{ field.data }}"/>
{# use basename for local id purposes and display value as label for users #}
{% elif field.name == 'targetBase' %}
    <label for="{{ field.id }}-{{ uniqueName }}">{{ uniqueName }}</label>
    <input name="{{ field.id }}-{{ uniqueName }}" id="{{ field.id }}-{{ uniqueName }}" type="hidden" value="{{ field.data }}"/>
{% endif %}
</p>
{% endmacro %}
```